# Wordpress: Feature Image won't change its size

Tags: php, wordpress, css-selectors

In my theme's ***function.php:***

```
//Custom Image Sizes
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150, true );
add_image_size( 'kaira-slider', 1140, 500, true );
add_image_size( 'kaira-featured', 652, 375, true );
add_image_size( 'kaira-grid-post', 360, 230, true );
```

And in my ***content.php:***

```
<div class="featured-img">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('kaira-featured', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
```

I tried to change the size from **'kaira-slider'** to **'kaira-featured'**, but the size won't change. I'm using the kaira-Theme.

How to force the theme to change the image size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote yourself, you need to change this in your CSS. So, go to the page where you want the displayed image to have a different size and use the browser developer tools to find out which CSS selector is used to address that image. Most likely this will be  a selector consisting of more than one tag and class (which is why it's not so easy to overwerite it)

Then use that same CSS selector in your custom CSS / stylesheet and define a different width (and most likely "height: auto" to keep the correct proportion).

Answer (score 2):

After any change of image size you must to regenerate the all images thumbnails.

For regenerate use [Regenerate thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.

Comment: I installed the plugin and set up the size. Still nothing happens. :( I hate the kiara theme.

Comment: @RamónWilhelm Did u run the the progress of regeneration?

Go to this link (just change to your domain) :
`http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=regenerate-thumbnails`

and hit the "Regenerate All Thumbnails" button.

Answer (score 1):

add_image_size( 'kaira-featured', 652, 375, true );

Change the values 652 and 375 to whatever you like

Comment: Even if I change the values the image won't change.

Comment: Change the 150, 150 to 250, 250

Answer (score 0):

Change:

the_post_thumbnail('kaira-featured', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));

To:
the_post_thumbnail('kaira-featured');

Comment: Nothing still happend. Do you need some code from other php-files?

Comment: I looked in the css of the theme and there was something with max-width: 100%. No wonder it didn't work.

Comment: I found out the css max-width is not the problem. Something in my theme isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if I wasted your time. But I also thank you for trying to help me.
I tried to modify the sizes via PHP. I started another way and I'm solving my problem with CSS, even it is a lot of work.

I don't understand why the **Kaira Theme** is so stubborn.
Theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/kaira/
Unfortunately it is the only theme that are fitting to my blog. Otherwise I should have changed it already.

Edit: I used to follow these instruction - useless. Not for the comlicated Kaira Theme
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/